# Math operations on time values

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I need to divide two delay parameter values which are in `ps`. The result has to be an integer value. I have tried the code below, but the result is incorrect. `N`, a parameter which I need at compile/elaboration time, needs to be calculated to `60`. Link on [edaplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Bh3).

```
module test #(parameter delay=3000ps, unitDelay = 50ps, integer N=$ceil(delay/unitDelay))
                    (input logic L, output logic R);

    initial begin
          $display ("delay=%d, unitDelay=%d, N=%d", delay, unitDelay, N);
          $display ("delay=%t, unitDelay=%t, N=%d", delay, unitDelay, N);
        end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your global timescale is `1ns`, so `unitDelay` will be 0. So you either need to make your timescale `1ps`, or change your parameter types to `real`